# RNN model with Keras predicts same entity

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using Keras to train an RNN model to predict some texts (NER), the training goes well and evaluation also.
Problem arises on the predict function where it predicts the same label to all elements on my string.

Sample input:

```
{"id":5256,"text":"SOME DUMMY DATA","label":[[0,4,"TAG1"],[5,10,"TAG2"]],"Comments":[]}
```

**prepare data**

```
import json
# Load the data
with open('data.jsonl', 'r') as f:
    reader = f.readlines()
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in reader]


# Create sequences and labels
import re 

def create_sequences(data):
    sequences = []
    labels = []
    for entry in data:
        text = entry['text']
        #lets make sure we dont split the entities
        words_and_spaces = re.findall(r'\S+|\s+', text)
        label = ['O'] * len(words_and_spaces)
        current_position = 0
        for label_info in entry['label']:
            start, end, label_type = label_info
            word_or_space_buffer = []
            for i, word_or_space in enumerate(words_and_spaces):
                next_position = current_position + len(word_or_space)
                if current_position >= start and next_position <= end:
                    word_or_space_buffer.append(word_or_space)
                    if next_position == end:
                        words_and_spaces[i-len(word_or_space_buffer)+1:i+1] = [''.join(word_or_space_buffer)]
                        label[i-len(word_or_space_buffer)+1:i+1] = ['O'] * len(word_or_space_buffer)
                        label[i] = label_type
                current_position = next_position
        sequences.append(words_and_spaces)
        labels.append(label)
    return sequences, labels




sequences, labels = create_sequences(data)
```

**train**

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Embedding, TimeDistributed
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder



# Prepare the tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sequences)

# Convert texts to sequences
X_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sequences)

# Pad sequences
X_padded = pad_sequences(X_seq, maxlen=100)

# Label encoding
le = LabelEncoder()
labels_flat = [label for sublist in labels for label in sublist]
le.fit(labels_flat)

# Convert labels to sequences and pad them
Y_seq = [le.transform(label) for label in labels]
Y_padded = pad_sequences(Y_seq, maxlen=100)

# One-hot encode labels
Y_categorical = np.array([to_categorical(y, num_classes=len(le.classes_)) for y in Y_padded])

# Split into training and validation sets
X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(X_padded, Y_categorical, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=len(tokenizer.word_index)+1, output_dim=100))

model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(len(le.classes_), activation='softmax')))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train model
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_val, Y_val), epochs=8)

# save model
model.save('i7d.keras')
```

**predict**

```
def predict(text):
    words_and_spaces = re.findall(r'\S+|\s+', text)

    # Tokenize and pad the sequence
    new_sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([words_and_spaces])
    new_sequence_padded = pad_sequences(new_sequence, maxlen=100)

    # Make a prediction
    predictions = model.predict(new_sequence_padded)
    # print(predictions)

    # The prediction is a sequence of one-hot encoded labels, so we need to convert it back to the original labels
    prediction_labels = [le.inverse_transform([np.argmax(pred)]) for pred in predictions[0]]

    # Print the results
    for word, label in zip(words_and_spaces, prediction_labels):
        print(f"{word}: {label}")
```